# How to stop copying the dates of a drop down list? I have used a while loop

Tags: javascript

My homework goes like this:

> We have to create a simple dropdown list using JavaScript HTML. The drop down lists are the year, month, and date - a simple calendar. The only thing that we have to do is to change the dates to 29 if February is in Leap Year. My problem is that every time I change the year and month, the date drop down list just add up the loop, like it copies the dates which supposedly it has only 1-31 days; turns into 1-31 and adds up another 1 - 30.

I have tried to change the codes. But if there's any simple way to change the codes or add something to make the dates "not to copy the
 dates which aren't for that month".

```js
function load() {
  var num = 1900;
  while (num <= 2019) {
    document.getElementById('s').innerHTML += "<option>" + num + "</option>";
    num++;
  }
}
//I add a function
function adonis() {
  var month = document.getElementById("mon").value;
  var year = document.getElementById("s").value;
  var x = 1;
  if (year % 4 == 0 && month == "February") {
    while (x <= 29) {
      document.getElementById("day").innerHTML += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
      x++;
    }
  } else if (month == "January" || month == "March" || month == "May" || month == "July" || month == "August" || month == "October" || month == "December" && year == 0) {
    while (x <= 31) {
      document.getElementById("day").innerHTML += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
      x++;
    }
  } else if (month == "April" || month == "June" || month == "September" || month == "November" && year == 0) {
    while (x <= 30) {
      document.getElementById("day").innerHTML += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
      x++;
    }
  } else if (month == "February" && year % 4 == !0) {
    while (x <= 28) {
      document.getElementById("day").innerHTML += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
      x++;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="load()">
  <select id="s" onchange="adonis()">

  </select>
  <select id="mon" onchange="adonis()">
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
    <option>April</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>
    //This is the date drop down list. It seems that it copies the dates once I change the year and month.
  </select>
  <select id="day" onchange="abela()">

  </select>
</body>
```

> I expect the output of the dates to be 1, 2, 3 ... 31. Not like 1 -
>   31 and another 1 - 31.
>   [This is the thing I really don't know to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImSLT.png)

Comment: In `adonis`, set `.innerHTML` to `''` first and then add values to it

Comment: In addition to this, you can take reference from the code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109765/javascript-date-validation). It uses jQuery, but you can reuse the calculation/creation logic and skip jQuery part

Comment: What do you mean set . innerHTML to ' ' ?

Comment: Yes. `.innerHTML = ''`. Then `... .innerHTML = ...`

Comment: In which part? @Raj

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is you're only ever using:

> .innerHTML +=

You're not resetting the contents.  Add the following to the start of your function:

> .innerHTML = '';

You can use the Date object and array functions to simplify this problem.

Take a look at the following for generating the options HTML.

```
//month is zero based index (Jan = 0)
function getDateOptions(year, month) {
  //Create an array with all dates
  var dates = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31];
  //use the date function to get the last day of the month
  var lastDate = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
  //reduce the array to just the valid dates
  dates = dates.splice(0, lastDate);
  //use the join function to generate the html
  return '<option>' + dates.join('</option><option>') + '</option>';
}

//Run for Feb
getDateOptions(2019, 1)
```

Comment: Where to add that .innerHTML = ";?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is almost correct with just minor change. You need to clear out list before you add new values to it

```js
function load() {
  var num = 1900;
  while (num <= 2019) {
    document.getElementById('s').innerHTML += "<option>" + num + "</option>";
    num++;
  }
}
//I add a function
function adonis() {
  var month = document.getElementById("mon").value;
  var year = document.getElementById("s").value;
  var x = 1;
  document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = '';
  if (year % 4 == 0 && month == "February") {
    while (x <= 29) {
      document.getElementById("day").innerHTML += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
      x++;
    }
  } else if (month == "January" || month == "March" || month == "May" || month == "July" || month == "August" || month == "October" || month == "December" && year == 0) {
    while (x <= 31) {
      document.getElementById("day").innerHTML += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
      x++;
    }
  } else if (month == "April" || month == "June" || month == "September" || month == "November" && year == 0) {
    while (x <= 30) {
      document.getElementById("day").innerHTML += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
      x++;
    }
  } else if (month == "February" && year % 4 == !0) {
    while (x <= 28) {
      document.getElementById("day").innerHTML += "<option>" + x + "</option>";
      x++;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="load()">
  <select id="s" onchange="adonis()">

  </select>
  <select id="mon" onchange="adonis()">
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
    <option>April</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>
    //This is the date drop down list. It seems that it copies the dates once I change the year and month.
  </select>
  <select id="day" onchange="abela()">

  </select>
</body>
```

As an alternate approach, you can try this:

There is a trick where you can jump to previous day using Date calculator (*Passing date as 0*). If you do that, you have last day of the month. Use this date and loop over it to create options.

Also, overriding/ updating in loop is a bad idea. Instead, create a html string and append it to perform bulk operation.

```js
function load() {
  var num = 1900;
  while (num <= 2019) {
    document.getElementById('s').innerHTML += "<option>" + num + "</option>";
    num++;
  }
}

function adonis() {
  var month = document.getElementById("mon").value;
  var year = document.getElementById("s").value;
  var noOfDays = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  var options = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= noOfDays; i++) {
    options += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
  }
  document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = options;
}
```

```html
<body onload="load()">
  <select id="s" onchange="adonis()">

  </select>
  <select id="mon" onchange="adonis()">
    <option value='1'>January</option>
    <option value='2'>February</option>
    <option value='3'>March</option>
    <option value='4'>April</option>
    <option value='5'>May</option>
    <option value='6'>June</option>
    <option value='7'>July</option>
    <option value='8'>August</option>
    <option value='9'>September</option>
    <option value='10'>October</option>
    <option value='11'>November</option>
    <option value='12'>December</option>
    //This is the date drop down list. It seems that it copies the dates once I change the year and month.
  </select>
  <select id="day" onchange="abela()">

  </select>
</body>
```